# GCC as m68k cross-compiler

Tags: c, gcc, cross-compiling, 68000

I am trying to recompile binutils and GCC as a cross-compiler for m68k architecture. I am following these instructions:

http://darkdust.net/writings/megadrive/crosscompiler

However, the process keeps failing on one part or another. I have tried with binutils 2.16.1 and gcc 3.4.6, binutils 2.15 and gcc 3.4.2 and binutils 2.15 and gcc 3.4.6.

This last attempt fails when running "make" on gcc, after making and installing binutils. It gives the following error:

```
gcc   -g -O2 -DIN_GCC -DCROSS_COMPILE  -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wstrict-
prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -pedantic -Wno-long-long    -DHAVE_CONFIG_H    
-I. -I. -I../../gcc-3.4.2/gcc -I../../gcc-3.4.2/gcc/. -I../../gcc-
3.4.2/gcc/../include   \
-DTARGET_MACHINE=\"m68k-coff\" \
-c ../../gcc-3.4.2/gcc/collect2.c -o collect2.o

In file included from /usr/include/fcntl.h:289:0,
             from ../../gcc-3.4.2/gcc/system.h:214,
             from ../../gcc-3.4.2/gcc/collect2.c:30:

In function ‘open’,
inlined from ‘collect_execute’ at ../../gcc-3.4.2/gcc/collect2.c:1535:20:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl2.h:50:4: error: call to 
‘__open_missing_mode’ declared with attribute error: open with O_CREAT or 
O_TMPFILE in second argument needs 3 arguments
__open_missing_mode ();
^
Makefile:1364: recipe for target 'collect2.o' failed
make[1]: *** [collect2.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/gabriel/src/gcc-build/gcc'
Makefile:23339: recipe for target 'all-gcc' failed
make: *** [all-gcc] Error 2
```

I don't expect to fix this error, but does anyone know of a combination of binutils and gcc release that work? Should I be using a certain version of gcc to recompile gcc successfuly?

Thanks for any insight you may have on this!

EDIT:

My linux has GCC 5.4.0 so I just downloaded the 5.4.0 source to try and rebuild that for m68k cross-compiling. I now get the following error when running "make" on the gcc source:

```
*** Configuration m68k-unkown-coff not supported
```

What could be the cause of this? Is it because I need an older version of GCC? (the binutils version i'm using definately supports the m68k target). The tutorial I'm using always defines "--target=m68k-coff", should that instead be "--target=m68k-unkown-coff"?

EDIT 2:

So I tried compiling for m68k-elf but now I get this error:

```
checking for m68k-elf-gcc... /home/gabriel/src/gcc-build/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/gabriel/src/gcc-build/./gcc/ -B/opt/m68k/m68k-elf/bin/ -B/opt/m68k/m68k-elf/lib/ -isystem /opt/m68k/m68k-elf/include -isystem /opt/m68k/m68k-elf/sys-include
checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/home/gabriel/src/gcc-build/m68k-elf/libgcc':
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
```

I ran download_prerequisites before building so it should not be a problem with the MPC library. Any idea how to move on? I need assembler only so I don't mind what the format of the object files is. Thanks!

Comment: Don't try to build old versions of GCC with newer versions. Either do a bootstrap build or get a newer version.

Comment: Thanks, that's one problem solved! Could you please check my edit and tell me if you know how to go on?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=42557#c5

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I ran into a new error. Could you check my new edit? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @aspirino67 which hardware are you targetting? there's a gcc 6.2 port for 68000 available (Amiga, but maybe works for other machines). Also check vbcc.

Comment: 68k support in gcc is commonly known to *not being improved* (rather the opposite) since 2.95. Recent gccs in my experience produce a lot of really silly 68k code. My recommendation would be to use an older version (compiled with an older version)

Comment: @tofro: you might have look at gcc-6.5.0b for the Amiga

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to do pretty much what you are doing right now.

My advice is to use crosstool-ng (http://crosstool-ng.github.io), as it does pretty much everything in an automated manner.

If you are studying m68k assembly, I used to host a modified version of gcc-explorer by Matt Godbolt (https://godbolt.org/). You can find a runnable docker image here (https://hub.docker.com/r/esantoro/acso-explorer/) and some more details here (https://znpy.wordpress.com/2017/05/08/decommisioning-acso-explorer-santoro-tk/)

### Hope it helps,

znpy

Answer (score 1):

you can build most versions with a current Linux. To install the prerequisites have a look at https://github.com/bebbo/amiga-gcc

- unpack the gcc archive, e.g. to /opt/cross/gcc-6.5.0
- create a separate build folder, e.g. /opt/cross/xcc-6.5.0 - never build inside gcc's source folder!
- create the prefix folder, that's where binaries are installed to, e.g. /opt/cross/gcc65
- ensure that these folders exist and are writable, then
- configure from within that build folder using an absolute path for configure

  ```
  cd /opt/cross/xcc-6.5.0/
  /opt/cross/gcc-6.5.0/configure --target=m68k-elf --program-prefix=m68k-elf- --enable-languages=c,c++ --prefix=/opt/cross/gcc65 --disable-libssp --disable-nls --disable-multilib
  make all-gcc
  make install-gcc
  ```

I'm also running the compiler explorer for 68k gccs at https://franke.ms/cex/